# Is it possible to test offline mode on android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I wonder if it possible to test offline mode on android emulator? Im trying to use ddms for this. But when i set telephony status data to "denied" or "unregistered" nothing changes and application still can receive data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop Internet access on the emulator android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235501/stop-internet-access-on-the-emulator-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Telephony Offline/Online Mode :

You can Toggle cell networking on/off by pressing F8

You can refer full Controls Of Emulator here :
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#controlling

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>F8</kbd> didn't work for me.

To test offline functionality in my Android emulator, I use the phone's settings to put the emulator in Airplane Mode, or shut off **both** cellular and WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

If you are speaking about the cell network, press f8 to toggle it on/off: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html